# PyCharm not showing dataframe when I press ctrl+alt+f10

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, yfinance

I'm trying to backtest a simple strategy of mine and the first step is to retrieve historical data from yfinance. However, whenver I run this, I can't see the contents of *hist*. Instead, it just has this output[this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDUnI.png)

```
# import all the libraries
import nsetools as ns
import pandas as pd
import numpy
from datetime import datetime
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

plot.style.use('classic')
a = input("Enter the ticker name you wish to apply strategy to")
ticker = yf.Ticker(a)
hist = ticker.history(period="1mo", interval="5m")
hist
```

I really just want to see the historical prices against the time but can't get the dataframe to appear. I would appreciate any input on this.

Comment: Try `print(hist)`. Your code will show results in an interactive environment like Idle, but not in PyCharm.

Comment: That worked. Thanks, I am a complete noob in python and didn't know that.